# (Swift, Xcode) How to prevent reloading of ViewController when segue back from SWRevealController?

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealController and 4 viewControllers. How can I make it so that the viewControllers only load once and switching back to them using SWReveal won't reload them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the `SWRevealController` does not work that way, and its probably correct that it does not. The view controllers are disposed as per their lifecycle once they are removed from the display stack (when you select another view controller), from a menu perhaps I assume.

Considering the situation you have asked for, the only way I can see it working is that if you keep all the 4 ViewControllers in your memory using a 'hack' and do not dispose them ever, which is not recommended since you are consuming precious memory, and your solution may not be very scalable. For example, if you have 10 view controllers tomorrow, you'll end up consuming more memory.

Please have a look at this thread for more clarity: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/230

Hope this answers your question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for answering. What if I had WKWebViews on all of the viewControllers and wanted to keep the scroll position / pages on the viewControllers without having to refresh?

Comment: I do not know how the WKWebView works (never used it), but since your viewController will be removed from the memory, I don't think that your webview would be preserved as well. You would probably need to figure out a way to cache your data someway, (again we are talking about a good amount of data since this is HTML and I won't recommend it), and the scroll position as well.